# How to change text size according to screen size

Tags: nvidia, opensuse, monitors

I'm using a Dell Precision 7770 laptop running openSUSE Leap 15.5 and using NVIDIA drivers and the KDE window manager. All software is up to date with latest supported versions. Normally I run it with a 28" 4K external monitor, and I have the font sizes set to be comfortable for that screen. If I'm away from home I don't take the big monitor with me, so I use the laptop's  built-in 17" 4K screen, and text is much smaller and hard to read. I would like to be able to set different font scaling according to which screen I'm using.

I think that nvidia-settings used to be able to have different settings for different screens, but the version on my system, which seems to be the latest for my hardware and OS, doesn't appear to support this, see [image: attached screenshot].

I tried setting the Global scale in System Settings->Display Configuration and selecting "For only this specific display arrangement", but it seems to set the scale for both screens.

How do I set a separate font scaling for each screen?